# Adding a Writer Monad inside foldl function Haskell

Tags: haskell

I implemented a function that searched for a specific node inside a tree.
Here's the function and it works:

```
searchTree :: String -> Tree String -> Bool
searchTree value tree =
    foldl (\acc x -> if value `elem` x then True else acc) False (levels tree)
```

Then, I'm trying to implement the same function, but this time, I want to add a Writer Monad. This one doesn't work and the compiler says "Couldn't match expected type 'Writer [String] Bool' with actual type 'Bool' " -> The error is in the 4th line, in the instruction 'return True'.

```
searchTree :: String -> Tree String -> Writer [String] Bool
searchTree value tree =
    foldl (\acc x -> if value `elem` x then do
        tell ["My logger message "]
        return True else acc) return False (levels tree)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis around `return False`:

```
searchTree :: String -> Tree String -> Writer [String] Bool
searchTree value tree =
    foldl (\acc x -> if value `elem` x then do
        tell ["My logger message "]
        return True else acc) (return False) (levels tree)
```

Tip: To make such bugs easier to find, I always remove my hard-coded type signatures, because the problem may be that I'm misunderstanding types. In this case removing the type signature changed the error to:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `m0 a0' 
Expected type: a0 -> Bool 
Actual type: a0 -> m0 a0 
In the second argument of `foldl', namely `return'
In the expression:
    foldl (\acc x -> if value `elem` x then do
        tell ["My logger message "]
        return True else acc) (return False) (levels tree)
```

Comment: I should add for clarity that it's good to put the explicit type signatures back once you've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in cases like these,  you (usually) really do want to use `foldr` instead.

```
searchTree :: String -> Tree String -> Writer [String] Bool
searchTree value tree =
    foldr (\x continue -> if value `elem` x then do
        tell ["My logger message "]
        return True else continue) (return False) (levels tree)
```

The reasons being,  this won't inspect the entire list,  but stop at the first `elem value x`,  in most cases (the writer monad included) associating `(>>=)` to the right is more efficient than associating to the left,  and `foldr` is compatible with GHC's list fusion whereas `foldl` is not.